# UITableView cellspace in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

We used `UITableView` at our gallery, I removed cell spaces with `frame.size.height`, but when i scroll down and up it appears again. How can we remove them permanently?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : FotograflarKategoriCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FotograflarKategoriCell
    cell.lblKategoriAdi.text = ArrayFotoKategori[indexPath.row].KategoriAdi
    let url = URL(string: ArrayFotoKategori[indexPath.row].KategoriResim)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           cell.FotografUrl.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.ArrayFotoKategori[indexPath.row].KategoriResim))
        }
    }

    class FotograflarKategoriCell: UITableViewCell {
        override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            var frame = newValue
            frame.size.height += 25
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your frame grows every time you change it. Don't override `frame` like this.

Comment: so how can i do it ? Any suggestion?

Comment: instead of table view use collection view